# Need desktop LGA1151 motherboard w/ Windows Server Access Control Service, VT-d, & APICv

Tags: processor, motherboard, server, virtual-machines

I want to enable passthrough of my [GeForce RTX 2080Ti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_20_series) GPU in Windows Server (2019 preferred) using  [DDA](http://www.cpu-world.com/Glossary/D/Dual_Dynamic_Acceleration.html). I need to buy another motherboard, since my current [Gigabyte AORUS Pro](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/Z390-AORUS-PRO-rev-10/sp#sp) motherboard will not support the [ACS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Control_Service) ([more on ACS](https://books.google.com/books?id=1SnVDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT182&lpg=PT182&dq=%22Windows%20Server%22%20%22Access%20Control%20Service%22%20-Azure&source=bl&ots=_dRe1Fw0wb&sig=ACfU3U2ng5tdxeln4uJI4Rhc_wu3wdgrmg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR0fX467PpAhWLv54KHVddAzgQ6AEwCHoECGEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Windows%20Server%22%20%22Access%20Control%20Service%22%20-Azure&f=false)).

I don't want to buy another CPU, as this is for pleasure and for learning, and want to reuse my [i9-9900K](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/186605/intel-core-i9-9900k-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz.html) CPU and existing DDR4 XMP non-ECC memory.

Also, I would spend more or less [200 Euros](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=shop&sxsrf=ALeKk00wGMOBg4ViboqHbi3lJdXl-zgg0g:1589404278705&psb=1&q=LGA1151+motherboard&tbs=vw:l,mr:1,price:1,ppr_max:183,cat:289,pdtr0:713223%7C1010359,new:1,init_ar:SgVKAwihAkoKUggIh8QrILfVPQ%3D%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK1L6r4LHpAhXTu54KHSuqDQkQsysIqxEoAA&biw=1536&bih=684).

Which i9-9900K compatible [FCLGA1151](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1151#LGA_1151_revision_2) (LGA 1151 Gen2) motherboards using DDR4 memory support ACS. VT-d, and APICv (so the graphic card can be assigned to the guest OS) do  you suggest?

Comment: APICv ; SR-IOV and VT-D ; only ATX.

Comment: I can't use a micro ATX case because the graphic card will not fit inside.

Comment: I don't care,but I prefer 2019,since I have already installed it.

Comment: I use this RAM model : HyperX-Predator-DDR4-HX430C15PB3K2-32

Comment: I can't use a micro ATX motherboard,it is too small. Is there a better choice ?

Comment: ok. I can consider to change my ATX mobo with a micro or mini one. I will place it inside my big tower. But which mobos are u suggesting me ?

Comment: anyway,man,how can I send one inquiry to asus,asrock,gigabyte and so on if they ask me to use a serial number ? I haven't any serial number. my question is not tied to a specific piece of hardware.

Comment: I sent emails directly to links I had saved in the past for manufacturer support. No response yet, except for Gigabyte who wanted me to confirm which model failed for you. To make room for new Comments, you can click delete after any Comment of yours which has been resolved. BTW, the link in the third graf of my answer is also set to filter out motherboards > US$183 which would allow for 200 Euros less a 17% VAT; if your VAT is higher, please advise. And, what does _more or less_ 200 Euros mean?

Answer (score 2):

A.  Gigabyte Tech Support asks you to contact them to obtain the Z390AORUSPROGA9.zip BIOS and apply it to your existing motherboard. See https://pastebin.com/uqYt3rmx for details of their response. I regret I can't provide a direct link to the BIOS update file they suggested, so you have to contact them to get it.

B. Gigabyte TS replied and suggested their [ASUS ROG STRIX Z390-H GAMING](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-Z390-H-GAMING/) which is [US$190](https://www.newegg.com/asus-rog-strix-z390-h-gaming/p/N82E16813119158), but is not available right now at NewEggUK.  See https://pastebin.com/SZw4Rfw0 for their suggestion and contact information on item B.

I would make sure to contact Gigabyte yourself and confirm this product meets all of your specifications, and make sure your vendor will accept a no charge return if it does not.

A week later, no other vendors queried have replied to my question regarding your specifications.

Comment: hello. I've been lucky because one of my friends has the motherboard "asus rog strix z390-f" and I asked to him to check if it is good for the passthrough of my graphic card and he made the test "survey-dda.ps1". The result has been that the mobo is capable only to pass this device "Samsung NVMe Controller : Express Endpoint -- more secure.And its interrupts are message-based, assignment can work. PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1B04)#PCI(0000)" its not enough for me. Anyway,thanks.

Comment: The ASUS ROG Strix Z390-F https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-Z390-F-GAMING/ is different from the ASUS ROG STRIX Z390-H GAMING https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-Z390-H-GAMING/ so testing on the "F" motherboard does not mean the "H" motherboard won't meet your specs.

Comment: Hello. I would like to contact the Gigabyte Tech Support to obtain the file Z390AORUSPROGA9 to upgrade my BIOS,but on the pastebin that u have provided there isn't any email that I can send an email and it's not easy at all to find the right one. Can u provide the email and I will do the rest ? thanks.

Comment: Go to https://esupport.gigabyte.com/#id:818291 and create an account. Then, create a new question something like "I want to enable the passthrough of my GeForce RTX 2080Ti GPU in Windows Server using DDA. My current Gigabyte AORUS Pro motherboard will not support the ACS.and I have heard about a new BIOS, Z390AORUSPROGA9.zip" and refer to  id:874899

Comment: do u know a tool that can tell me what's the SN of my motherboard ? I've followed some tutorials on youtube but I haven't been able to get it via software. I wouldn't open the case if possible. But without the SN I can't make any question to gigabyte.

Comment: it says : λ wmic bios get serialnumber
=SerialNumber
=Default string

Comment: Run that from a Windows Command Prompt.

Comment: already done. It is not able to get it. Maybe because I'm using Windows 10 insider build.

Comment: it does not work even with linux : # dmidecode 3.2

 Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
 Product Name: Z390 AORUS PRO-CF
 Version: x.x
 Serial Number: Default string
 Asset Tag: Default string

Handle 0x0021, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
Description:    To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Comment: Then, guess you have to open the case to comply with their rules. DOn't know what to tell you; somehow I got them to respond without providing a serial number. Maybe try _na_ in that field?